# как из строки сделать массив

Tags: javascript

как можно сделать из строки например "Press,Moderators,Speakers" чтобы был массив `arr = ["Press", "Moderators", "Speakers"]`

```
var string = "Press,Moderators,Speakers";
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var string = "Press,Moderators,Speakers";
var arr = string.split(',')
```

Answer (score 4):

Есть замечательный метод **split**

```
let string = "blue,red,green";

let newArr = string.split(",");

console.log(newArr);
```